# Negligible Mass of String

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, string, approximations

I've recently been working through a lot of physics problems and a lot of them say to assume that the mass of the string used in a problem involving a pulley, for example, is negligible. Why is this important? What would happen if the mass of the string wasn't negligible?

Comment: For starters the tension in the string would not be the same at all points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the mass of the string wasn't negligible, say it was 0.1 g/cm, then this would happen:

The bottom-most point of the string would be holding up just the mass (*M*) that is suspended on it.

A point 10 cm above would be holding *M* plus 1 g.

A point 20 cm above the bottom would be holding *M* plus 2 g.

Since the "mass that the point is holding" is actually the tension in the string at that point, the tension in the string would vary with the position. This, as you should know, will change the forces on both sides of the pulley, and things would be quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Mass of string is negligible because if it wasn't negligible you would require more effort to pull it and friction will also be less between the string and grooved rim